# Matlab : Is the square operation in real domain the Conjugate operation in complex domain?

Tags: matlab, math, complex-numbers

I am trying to evaluate the expression `z = (x-y)^2` in real domain and its corresponding adaptation in complex domain. For real domain, this expression is implemented as 
let

```
x = 5;
y = 2;
z = (x-y)^2

z =

     9
```

In  complex domain, the expression would become (please correct me if wrong )

`z_c = (x_c - y_c)(x_c - y_c)*` This is implemented in Matlab by

```
>> x_c = 5 + 0.9i;
 y_c = 2 - 0.34i;
 z_c = (x_c-y_c)*conj((x_c -y_c))
z_c =

   10.5376
```

The `*` operator for conjugate in maths is implemented by `conj()`

The answers are different and am I using the correct operator?

Comment: What makes you say "the" square of a complex number is `z·z*`?  The regular square of a complex number ("the" square) is just `z·z`, and the [absolute square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteSquare.html) is `z·z*`. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to deal with that in MATLAB:

```
x = 5 + 2i;
y = 2 - 4i;

% Method A

(x - y) * conj(x - y);

% Method B

(x - y)' * (x - y);

% Method C

norm(x - y, 2) ^ 2;
```

The first method is using the Conjugate Operator.
This method is written assuming both `x` and `y` are scalar.

Method B is using the definition of Inner Product (The `'` is the Vector Adjoint Operator - Transpose and Conjugate).
It will work for vectors as well.

Method C is using the built in `norm()` function of MATLAB.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please also mention about how to adopt these 2 operations from real to complex domain? (1) `[.]^{-1}[\sum () ] ` where the terms in `[. ] ` square bracket is for matrix inverse and (2) if there is a scalar real valued number `a`, the operation is square of this term, `(a)^2` In complex domain, the value of `a` would be a complex number, then should I do `a * conj(a)` ?

Comment: Explain what you want to do, don't write the commands just the Math.

Comment: Lastly, (3) what would be the corresponding operations in complex domain for `a*a^T` and `a*b`

Comment: (1) If `a` is an array and when I want to multiply it with itself in real domain, I take its transpose and then perform multiplication. (2) Multiplication of two different scalar valued numbers. (3) multiplication of two same scalar valued numbers. What would be the corresponding adaptation of these three cases in complex domain?